# docker build gives insufficient space error

Tags: docker, yum, docker-registry

`docker build` gives this error all of a sudden...

Things we tried but none of them makes the error gone:

1. docker login to a different registry
2. docker rmi, docker rm
3. someone else does docker build in their local machine.

Logs:

```
One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).
     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...
     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:
            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>
     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:
            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base
    * free   0
    * needed 100 k
```

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same issue. It turned out that my Windows 10 laptop was running out of disk space resources that were assigned to Docker Desktop. If in your case you are running Docker Desktop you can increase the disk resource from Docker Desktop > Settings > Resources > Disk image size:
[image: Docker Desktop Resources Settings]

Comment: ...or other option is to do some cleanup on your machine if you don't want to increase the disk image size resources. You can clean the dangling images with `docker image prune` command. 
Ref. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/